# OpenCV linking issue on BeagleBone Black and Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, linker, arm, beagleboneblack

I have [BeagleBone Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black) with [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin). I downloaded the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) library from apt using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev
```

This command installed required headers and libraries. Then I compiled my own program which is just showing a window with the following command:

```
gcc -I/usr/inlcude/ -I/usr/include/opencv2/ -L/usr/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lm opencv_test.c -o test
```

After some seconds it shows that it is unable to find a reference with 'lrint' and many more and at last showing the linking errors for cvNameWindow, cvShowImage, etc.

I think that this may be the problem of installed libraries. I downloaded the latest OpenCV Source, cross compiled the code provided on the OpenCV wiki with `-DUSE_NEON=ON` flags on my Ubuntu machine. I copied these headers and libraries into the extra partition which is [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) formatted. Again I issued the follwing command:

```
gcc -I/usr/inlcude/ -I/media/misc/opencv/include/opencv/ -I/media/misc/opencv/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/media/misc/opencv/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lm opencv_test.c -o test
```

Note: /media/misc/ is the extra partition.

This command gives me the same output as earlier. Now I come to the point. Maybe I am not issuing the correct command.

Also I changed gcc to g++, and it gives me the errors like:

```
unable to find reference cvNamedWindow
unable to find reference cvShowImage
```

etc.

Comment: have you tried these two videos? www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sb0noQkTTjA‎ and www.youtube.com/watch?v=T29BLCh1I54‎

Comment: There is a typo error in your command line, you have -I/usr/inlcude/, but -I/usr/include/ should be correct. However I do not have opencv installed here to know what impact that may have.

Comment: yeah, but I didn't make a typo in existing command. Although, I am facing issues in linking the libraries.

Comment: I found a way, I downloaded Angstrom image, grabbed the opencv libraries, and included these libraries into my existing Beaglebone Sdcard Image manually. Now it is working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally compiled the sample code given in the OpenCV tarball, and that code compiled. Then I looked into the build script, and I found the following command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` $1 -o $2 `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

It is actually a script. `$1` is the first argument, that is a .cpp file, and `$2` is the second which is the output file. I use this script as follow:

```
./build_cv.sh opencv_test.cpp test
```

Note: make sure the script file "build_cv.sh" has execute permission. If not, then change its permission by typing:

```
chmod +x build_cv.sh
```

Now the problem. I was giving the location of header file and libraries in the first attempt. I have to give the location of headers before giving the source file, and location of the libraries after the output file. This is my experience; maybe some other guy have another way of compiling the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your link command has: `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lm opencv_test.c`

This is the *wrong* order of arguments. To understand why, read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

> If I give this command to my existing ubuntu x82 machine, It compiles very nicely...

You mean "it links very nicely".

That's happening by [coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence), not because your link command is correct.

Comment: If I give this command to my existing ubuntu x82 machine, It compiles very nicely...

Comment: Yes, that was coincidence, I changed my linking code, I followed the command given in samples/c/build_all.sh, it was:

    g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` $1 -o $2 `pkg-config --libs opencv`    (there are ticks, which are not showing)

now there is no issue in linking, thank you very much all of you  ....